# How can I write a beforeAction() that applies to all controllers?

Tags: php, yii

I want to register a script within the beforeAction method(Yii Framework). But I don't want to repeat that method in every single controller, so my question is how can i create a beforeAction() that all controllers will inherit?

Thx,

Comment: I don't recall exactly if yii is the same, but try to look for it in the bootstrap file, I had a similar problem in Zend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default yiic generated yii webapp has a Controller class in *project/protected/components/Controller.php* , and all controllers in the app inherit from this Controller.

That class is the perfect place to add the `beforeAction`.

**Edit:** Incase you have not used yiic and don't have this default Controller class, it's fine to add a new class that extends from CController, and then have your controllers extend from this new class. You can keep all the common functionality for your controllers in this parent controller class.

Comment: Nice, had the same thing in mind but needed some confirmation

Comment: ok great then, i made a small edit to make this answer work when not using yiic to generate app

Answer (score 0):

You need to create BaseController.php inside components directory. Inside this file you will inherit your BaseController from CController. Write your beforeAction there. After this you will need to inherit all you controllers from BaseController.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create Common parent Controller with extended with CController (example SomeController)

2) register script in the beforeAction()  in this Controller (example SomeController)

3) extend this controller of your SiteController or Module Controller.

```
<?php

class SomeController extends CController
{
    public function beforeAction()
    {
        // Your Register Script
    }
}


class SiteController extends SomeController
{
    // public function actionIndex
}
```